# CUDA floating point gives different results

Tags: image, cuda, grayscale

I am converting an image from colour to grayscale using CUDA 5 / VC 2008.

The CUDA kernel is:

```
__global__ static void rgba_to_grayscale( const uchar4* const rgbaImage, unsigned char * const greyImage,
                                     int numRows, int numCols) 
{
    int pos = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    if (pos < numRows * numCols) {
        uchar4 zz = rgbaImage[pos];
        float out = 0.299f * zz.x + 0.587f * zz.y + 0.114f * zz.z;
        greyImage[pos] = (unsigned char) out;
    }

}
```

The C++ function is:

```
inline unsigned char rgba_to_grayscale( uchar4 rgbaImage) 
{
    return (unsigned char) 0.299f * rgbaImage.x + 0.587f * rgbaImage.y + 0.114f * rgbaImage.z;
}
```

and they are both called appropriately. However they are yielding different results.

#### Original image :

[image: This colour image]

#### CUDA version:

[image: cuda result]

#### Serial CPU version:

[image: Serial Code result]

Can anybody explain why the results are different?

Comment: What is speedup ratio for this function?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no problem with your CUDA function. The CPU version is incorrect. You are typecasting the value `0.299f * rgbaImage.x` to `unsigned char` which is equivalent to the following code:

```
inline unsigned char rgba_to_grayscale( uchar4 rgbaImage) 
{
    return ((unsigned char) 0.299f * rgbaImage.x) + 0.587f * rgbaImage.y + 0.114f * rgbaImage.z;
}
```

You have to cast the final result into `unsigned char` like this:

```
inline unsigned char rgba_to_grayscale( uchar4 rgbaImage) 
{
    return (unsigned char) (0.299f * rgbaImage.x + 0.587f * rgbaImage.y + 0.114f * rgbaImage.z);
}
```

Comment: Yup - nearly there. But the other thing which I had vaguely remembered is that the RGBA order is different for the C and CUDA code. will post below.

Answer (score 0):

@sga91 was pretty much there.... but is also appears that the byte order is different.

```
inline unsigned char rgba_to_grayscale( uchar4 rgbaImage) 
{
    return (unsigned char) (0.299f * rgbaImage.z + 0.587f * rgbaImage.y + 0.114f * rgbaImage.y);
}
```

note that the x and z are transposed....

I do remember reading about it before but I cannot find the reference now...

Comment: I don't think the byte order should be different. It depends on the channel sequence of the input image. e.g RGBA or BGRA etc.

Comment: It appears that OpenGL uses BGRA and I think that this kind of migrates to CUDA - but I will try to get some absolute reference to it. But I agree that it looks crazy because I used the CUDA image load helper functions in both cases.